# Deleted targets keep working in xcode 6. Why?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, xcode6

I am developing an app in xcode 6 using several imported frameworks. When I created targets for the frameworks I did something wrong and I got undefined symbol in architecture 86x errors. I found no way to fix this problem and eventually I copied images.xcassets, Main.storyboard, and all my .swift files into my desktop and deleted the entire xcode project. I made a new xcode project and copied my resources back into my project.

What's strange is that the old import statements in the .swift files STILL WORK. The targets they reference cannot be found anywhere one my computer but my code still compiles. These targets that somehow still work, as I said above, cause errors at runtime and so I would like to get rid of them somehow instead of just making targets with new names. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to use some version control system (like git), because if you do something wrong then you can always revert to the last working copy. No need to delete or copy files & stuff.

Now the important part, why you got runtime/build errors. Sometimes some frameworks do not support some architecture, may be while creating the target you missed something related to architecture.

Next part, the project gets the reference of the frameworks, XCode don't copy all the files. Because you may use frameworks in different project thats why XCode refer the reference memory only.

Hope it helps.